# Error verifying certificate when using -wget

Tags: certificate

Hello I am very much a beginner in this field but I am attempting to use a -wget given by website to download a database. However I get the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot verify <domain name>'s certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3’:
  Issued certificate has expired.
To connect to <domain name> insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

I don't want to use the `--no-check-certificate` certificate, how else can I solve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cirtificate has expired, there is nothing you can do.
It's the responsibility of the domain owner to issue a new certificate.
I would advice you to not use `--no-check-certificate`, as a connection with an invalid certificate might not be secure.

If the domain owner wont issue a new certificate, you have no option besides ignoring the invalid certificate (`--no-check-certificate`).

Comment: Ah I see, thats very unfortunate. Thank you for your help